# Have to restart IntelliJ to run new/edited code?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Editing a program and then running it ignores all changes and runs the code that was present when IntelliJ was opened.

[image]
As you can see, my Main program was first just a Hello World, however when I write some new code in, running it will keep displaying that Hello World. The only thing that works is restarting IntelliJ each time, which is tedious.

I've tried various ways to run it, using the gutter run buttons, right-clicking the program and then running for example, reloading from disk, and also rebuilding, but none of these work, my only solution is to restart IntelliJ each time.

Am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like you are using remote development and running the code on the remote target (WSL). Deployment may be not configured correctly and your code is not updated on the remote. Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the sample project and the exact steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Is there a space in the path to your app?  Try removing the space. This resolved the same issue for me.